# amsrefs doesn't show the booktitle entry when compiling an @article bibliography item using BibTeX

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, amsrefs

Here's my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{amsrefs}   
\begin{document} 
blah \cite{ASD71}   
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

with references file `references.bib`:

```
@article {ASD71,
    AUTHOR = {Atkin, A. O. L. and Swinnerton-Dyer, H. P. F.},
     TITLE = {Modular forms on noncongruence subgroups},
 BOOKTITLE = {Combinatorics ({P}roc. {S}ympos. {P}ure {M}ath., {V}ol. {XIX},
              {U}niv. {C}alifornia, {L}os {A}ngeles, {C}alif., 1968)},
     PAGES = {1--25},
 PUBLISHER = {Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, R.I.},
      YEAR = {1971},
   MRCLASS = {10D05},
  MRNUMBER = {0337781},
MRREVIEWER = {Morris Newman},
}
```

But when I compile it, it doesn't show the `booktitle` or `publisher`. Is this normal? If I add a `journal` entry, then it does show the journal.

Comment: `@article`s don't have a `booktitle`. They have a `journal` instead. You seem to want an `@inproceedings` entry, those have a `booktitle`.

Comment: @moewe Aha! Thanks! Where can I find a list of "which article-types have which fields"?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX or even https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX could be a start. The exact fields supported depend on the style, so you might also want to check http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrdoc.pdf

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [User moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/35864/moewe) in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/399172/amsrefs-doesnt-show-most-of-the-bibtex-entry#comment993298_399172), the `@article` field does not take the entry `booktitle`, which is why it does not appear in your MCVE upon compiling.

Since you are using `amsrefs` with BibTeX, to find out which fields are admissable you need to look at the documentation for the AMS Export BibTeX style: [amsxport.pdf](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsxport.pdf). In particular, look at Section 10 *Entry types* on page 15. Though there are 14 types of bibliography fields that BibTeX admits, `amsrefs` combines most of them together, and you really have only 3 types of fields:

1. **`@article`**: `author`, `translator`, `title`, `subtitle`, `language`, `organization`, `how`, `date`, `ISSN`, `journal`, `volume`, `number`, `pages`, `PII`, `archive`, `eprint`, `preprint`, `url`, `note`, `status`, `review`
2. **`@inproceedings`**: `author`, `translator`, `title`, `subtitle`, `language`, `organization`, `how`, `date`, `xid`, `conference`, `booktitle`, `edition`, `editor`, `series`, `volume`, `publisher`, `address`, `pages`, `url`, `note`, `status`, `review`
3. **`@book`**: `author`, `editor`, `translator`, `booktitle`, `title`, `subtitle`, `type`, `language`, `conference`, `edition`, `series`, `publisher`, `organization`, `institution`, `address`, `how`, `date`, `volume`, `number`, `ISBN`, `url`, `note`, `status`, `review`

In addition, it seems there are also entries `chapter`, `howpublished`, `key`, `meeting`, `month`, `mrnumber`, `part`, `school` and `year`, as well as the built-in `crossref`, as mentioned on pages 2–3 under Section 2 *Implementation*.

In your case, you want to use the `@inproceedings` field instead of the `@article` field. Making this change, the output now shows the `booktitle` entry.

[image: Screenshot of output with @incproceedings instead of @article.]